# Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}'

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, kibana

i badly need help here, i try to parse a json from a file. I got this json content from kibana dev tools, i plan to hit the elastic api, get the json result and get several fields from the json. here's my code

```
public class JSONParserTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {



        String the_json=readFile("/Users/ahmadasyary/Documents/sample.out", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        //System.out.println(the_json);
        JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject(the_json);
        JSONArray the_json_array = myjson.getJSONArray("profiles");

    }

    static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) 
              throws IOException 
            {
              byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
              return new String(encoded, encoding);
            }

}
```

When i try to run it, i got error like this

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at 3264 [character 25 line 64]
    at java.json/org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:432)
    at java.json/org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:223)
    at java.json/org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:362)
    at java.json/org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:208)
    at java.json/org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:362)
    at java.json/org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:117)
    at java.json/org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:365)
    at java.json/org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:208)
    at java.json/org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:362)
    at java.json/org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:208)
    at java.json/org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:310)
    at TDRParser/ParserTest.JSONParserTest.main(JSONParserTest.java:21)
```

Here's my json content from kibana devs tools

```
{
  "took": 89,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1015,
    "successful": 1015,
    "skipped": 970,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "project.prod-esb.cbd0dea7-4153-11e8-86d7-001a4a160175.2019.03.22",
        "_type": "com.redhat.viaq.common",
        "_id": "1KKHo2kB-rz4ABZ2mpyp",
        "_version": 1,
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "logTimestamp": "2019-03-22T10:52:46.251+07:00",
          "transactionID": "H003190322105245739910520",
          "logLevel": "AUDIT",
          "logPoint": "Transaction-Audit",
          "logMessage": "2019-03-22T10:52:45|2019-03-22T10:52:46|492|p0|H003190322105245739910520|p0169a3879784910520001101905fe5Sac000000000|TELKOMSEL||ACT|SELF|AIRTIME|0|||6281360791052|prepaid|Simpati|||prepaid|Simpati|22016||00011019|ML4_BP_22184|PO||Campaign|2019030761549|1|Days|5000.0|OT_002758_00011019_a5ffc884-19b1-11e9-80a8-cfff756b35c7|||Success|00000|Success||||002777:TC_002775_FLEXIBLEOFFER;00005679:TC_00005457_FLEXIBLEOFFER;00005696:TC_00005474_FLEXIBLEOFFER",
          "processTime": "492",
          "docker": {
            "container_id": "2a8e197e4bc9d849291e5457fdc7a238d684f92ccc19cf5f51b88772169acf0d"
          },
          "kubernetes": {
            "container_name": "ordersubmission-bs-v2",
            "namespace_name": "prod-esb",
            "pod_name": "ordersubmission-bs-v2-42-6n2rn",
            "pod_id": "5f417ed0-4b0d-11e9-89a5-001a4a160178",
            "labels": {
              "app": "ordersubmission-bs-v2",
              "deployment": "ordersubmission-bs-v2-42",
              "deploymentconfig": "ordersubmission-bs-v2"
            },
            "host": "esbwnpapp3.telkomsel.co.id",
            "master_url": "https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local",
            "namespace_id": "cbd0dea7-4153-11e8-86d7-001a4a160175"
          },
          "systemd": {
            "t": {
              "BOOT_ID": "ea8d4663351b44f9888b93042f680fcd",
              "CAP_EFFECTIVE": "1fffffffff",
              "CMDLINE": "/usr/bin/dockerd-current --add-runtime docker-runc=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-runc-current --default-runtime=docker-runc --authorization-plugin=rhel-push-plugin --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd --userland-proxy-path=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-proxy-current --log-driver=journald --storage-driver devicemapper --storage-opt dm.fs=xfs --storage-opt dm.thinpooldev=/dev/mapper/rhel-docker--pool --storage-opt dm.use_deferred_removal=true --storage-opt dm.use_deferred_deletion=true --mtu=1450 --add-registry registry.access.redhat.com --add-registry registry.access.redhat.com",
              "COMM": "dockerd-current",
              "EXE": "/usr/bin/dockerd-current",
              "GID": "0",
              "MACHINE_ID": "35ae721c7f2f4d2e9a0676e0d9e17589",
              "PID": "2722",
              "SELINUX_CONTEXT": "system_u:system_r:container_runtime_t:s0",
              "SYSTEMD_CGROUP": "/system.slice/docker.service",
              "SYSTEMD_SLICE": "system.slice",
              "SYSTEMD_UNIT": "docker.service",
              "TRANSPORT": "journal",
              "UID": "0"
            }
          },
          "level": "info",
          "message": """{"logMessageId":"","logTimestamp":"2019-03-22T10:52:46.251+07:00","transactionID":"H003190322105245739910520","serviceName":"","applicationID":"","logLevel":"AUDIT","logPoint":"Transaction-Audit","logMessage":"2019-03-22T10:52:45|2019-03-22T10:52:46|492|p0|H003190322105245739910520|p0169a3879784910520001101905fe5Sac000000000|TELKOMSEL||ACT|SELF|AIRTIME|0|||6281360791052|prepaid|Simpati|||prepaid|Simpati|22016||00011019|ML4_BP_22184|PO||Campaign|2019030761549|1|Days|5000.0|OT_002758_00011019_a5ffc884-19b1-11e9-80a8-cfff756b35c7|||Success|00000|Success||||002777:TC_002775_FLEXIBLEOFFER;00005679:TC_00005457_FLEXIBLEOFFER;00005696:TC_00005474_FLEXIBLEOFFER","requestPayload":"","responsePayload":"","processTime":"492"}""",
          "hostname": "esbwnpapp3.telkomsel.co.id",
          "pipeline_metadata": {
            "collector": {
              "ipaddr4": "10.130.14.2",
              "ipaddr6": "fe80::54d0:26ff:fe59:e4cd",
              "inputname": "fluent-plugin-systemd",
              "name": "fluentd",
              "received_at": "2019-03-22T03:52:46.883461+00:00",
              "version": "0.12.39 1.6.0"
            }
          },
          "@timestamp": "2019-03-22T03:52:46.252005+00:00"
        },
        "fields": {
          "logTimestamp": [
            "2019-03-22T03:52:46.251Z"
          ],
          "@timestamp": [
            "2019-03-22T03:52:46.252Z"
          ],
          "pipeline_metadata.collector.received_at": [
            "2019-03-22T03:52:46.883Z"
          ]
        },
        "highlight": {
          "logLevel.keyword": [
            "@kibana-highlighted-field@AUDIT@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
          ],
          "transactionID": [
            "@kibana-highlighted-field@H003190322105245739910520@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
          ],
          "kubernetes.container_name.keyword": [
            "@kibana-highlighted-field@ordersubmission-bs-v2@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          1553226766252
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "2": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key_as_string": "2019-03-22T10:52:46.000+07:00",
          "key": 1553226766000,
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I expect this issue can be solved without any manual changes on the json content, since it generated by kibana

Comment: The message doesn't seem like valid JSON.

Comment: It is not a valid JSON. The value of the message seems to be another JSON which is not properly escaped.

Comment: your JSON is invalid here https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer you can validate

Comment: Your JSON is not valid, validate it here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 2):

Just completely remove the double quotes occurring thrice for key: "message":

```
   "level": "info",
   "message": {"logMessageId":"","logTimestamp":"2019-03-22T10:52:46.251+07:00","transactionID":"H003190322105245739910520","serviceName":"","applicationID":"","logLevel":"AUDIT","logPoint":"Transaction-Audit","logMessage":"2019-03-22T10:52:45|2019-03-22T10:52:46|492|p0|H003190322105245739910520|p0169a3879784910520001101905fe5Sac000000000|TELKOMSEL||ACT|SELF|AIRTIME|0|||6281360791052|prepaid|Simpati|||prepaid|Simpati|22016||00011019|ML4_BP_22184|PO||Campaign|2019030761549|1|Days|5000.0|OT_002758_00011019_a5ffc884-19b1-11e9-80a8-cfff756b35c7|||Success|00000|Success||||002777:TC_002775_FLEXIBLEOFFER;00005679:TC_00005457_FLEXIBLEOFFER;00005696:TC_00005474_FLEXIBLEOFFER","requestPayload":"","responsePayload":"","processTime":"492"},
   "hostname": "esbwnpapp3.telkomsel.co.id",
```

It should work then, I am able to parse the file using below code snippet.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class JSONParserTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException {
    String the_json=readFile("sample.out", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    //System.out.println(the_json);
    JSONParser object = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = object.parse(the_json);
    JSONObject myjson = (JSONObject)obj;
    JSONArray the_json_array = (JSONArray)myjson.get("profiles");
    System.out.println(the_json_array);
}

static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) 
        throws IOException 
      {
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        return new String(encoded, encoding);
      }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In my cases it was " "(double quotes) issue when I replaced it with ' '(single quotes) it worked for me.
Please check sample after **data**.

This may work for you.

[image]